# Joomla where to set session which i can get in every component

Tags: php, session, joomla

I have tried to set session variable in template index.php file and it's working fine and getting that session variable every where.

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('CountryCode', 'in');
```

but there is problem when i open article using direct url in browser then first time i am getting session variable blank, but i refresh same page then i get session variable perfectly.

so, can you help me in which file i set session variable so that i get in each and every component of site, and also when i load page first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template rendering happens after the component execution.

You can try to create a system plugin which is executed before the component.

This link contains the available events where you can hook in. 
https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System#onAfterInitialise

Comment: can i put code direct in existsing plugin or file which render first? if yes can you give me file name?

Comment: you should not do this. Changing any core file will result in problems with updates. For a test you can enable the page cache plugin and modify the file plugins\system\cache\cache.php

Comment: yes its working, you are right, i have created plugin thanks